# How to retrieve uploaded file from a custom file system in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems

I have uploaded a file to my custom file system and it just works.

Custom File System:

```
'private' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/private'),
],
```

This is how I upload my files:

```
if ($request->hasFile('chatattachment')) {

    $file = request()->file('chatattachment');

    $fname = date('YmdHis');

    $ext = $request->chatattachment->extension();

    $filename = $fname . '.' . $ext;

    $file->storeAs('attachments', $filename, ['disk' => 'private']);


    //Trying to get the url but it doest work:
    $url = Storage::url('private/attachments/' . $filename);
}
```

Now, What I'm trying to do is to get the url of the newly uploaded image and return it back to the front end side. How to make it possible? I know how to create a storage:link but I don't want to expose this attachments to the public.

Comment: have you run php artisan storage:link to link the storage app folder? but as you are using private i assume you dont want it to be public?

Comment: @aimme yes, that's correct. that is why i did not use the storage:link command